# Images not showing in admin or front-end

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

All my images are not showing anymore on both the admin and the front-end. They are all replaced by the Magento placeholder.

When I check in `Catalog -> Manage Products`, select a product and click `Images`, the images are there (I have to hover over them to see them). Base, Small and Thumbnail are set an image in the Default Store View and all other Store Views are set "Use Default".

I see no errors in the backend, frontend or my HTTP logs.

I do see this message though:

> Image type and information need to be specified for each store view.

but there is nothing extra I can do in that screen other than supply a label. I tried Googling that error message, but found nothing I could use.

I tried flushing the cache, to no avail.

I am using version 1.9.3.10.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to reindex. Try it, and hope.

Comment: @FannyRibard all indexes are OK (btw, this reply sums up Magento: something doesn't work, no messages, and you just start trying stuff until it works. Is there anybody that *really* knows how it works... ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The problem was that I didn't have the GD library installed. I installed it with

```
~# yum install php56-php-gd
```

and the images showed up.

Of course, a nice message telling me that would have been nice...

Comment: Please post a descriptive answer so that other users can benefit from it as well.